# unsigned int value not giving correct result

Tags: c++

following program should print "error" but its printing success.why?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
   unsigned int a;
   a=-10;

   if(a == -10)
        cout << "success" ;
   else
        cout << "error" ;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that after `a = -10`, the variable `a` will differ from `-10`?

Comment: @David :-unsigned int will always be positive but assigning negative value shouldn't work so for unsigned int a = -10 should print error but it's printing success.so it is a confusion

Comment: I think I got confused from the question and the code. There are two different issues, one is whether the compiler should complain on the assignment. The other question is whether after accepting the assignment the comparison should be true or not. In the first case, the compiler does not need to complain as there is an available conversion, some will warn if you raise the warning level. In the second case, the only sensible thing is for the check to be true after the assignment. Given that `a = x` is a correct operation, after assignment it must hold that `a == x` whatever `a`'s value is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conversion for comparison makes them equal again. But it should cause the compiler to emit a warning.

Comment: Gah, I was staring at this trying to figure out why the OP found anything surprising, and didn't notice the `unsigned` specification. +1, anyway; this is exactly what happens.